# Webview Javascript Does Not Work in Android 7.0 and above

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I am making a dog whistle app using html5 to execute javascript and jquery webview.

The webview loads just fine but the Javascript fails to execute in my device on 7.0 and above.

With lollypop 5.0 and 5.5 devices, the javascript that the html calls works as expected. Everything compiles correctly.

The Logs do not log a thing on html5 button click after 7.0 when pushing the button to make the tone.

All of the files load locally from assets although I even enabled internet permissions. Is there a change at 7.0 which would stop javascript from working? Like I said before, everything works perfectly in lollypop. How would I fix?

Here is some code from my webview:
**EDITED: Nov 20 2019**

```
       WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
       WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
       webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) { webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); }
        String myurl="file:///android_asset/index.html";
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl(myurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `WebViewClient` and `WebChromeClient` for your browser.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

Comment: I did add both last week, It did not help unfortunately. Thank you very much for the assistance. Maybe its the order? I will update with the current code and please look at the order of everything. Thanks so much